# Redis access from MS Excel?

Tags: excel, key-value, redis

I would like to use redis to query data from commandline, scripts, web and from within spreadsheets.  I can find good examples for all but spreadsheets...
I don't quite know where to start for access from a MS Excel spreadsheet, though.  Google is failing me.

Please let me know how you would suggest doing this, thanks!

p.s. for those unfamiliar redis is a key-value datastore described here: http://code.google.com/p/redis/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found what I want with XLLoop http://xlloop.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

make yourself a RESTful/SOAP based webservice to wrap around the redis functionality you want to deploy, and then access it from excel.

excel web services toolkit http://oreilly.com/pub/h/1306