# Can data be pulled from Redis to excel

Tags: java, caching, redis

Can anyone give me an idea on how data can be pulled from redis cache to excel?

Can we pull data from Soap UI or need to write java code?

Thanks
Ekta

Comment: Maybe this link can help you.
[see post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356792/redis-access-from-ms-excel)

Comment: [this link](http://xlloop.sourceforge.net/) might help you. but I don't think you have tried googling around.